# Linux Time Zone Warning

Tags: linux, unix, centos, timezone, redhat

I'd like to know the meaning of the alert message that occurs in the Linux time zone.

timedatectl
Warning: Ignoring the TZ variable. Reading the system's time zone setting only.

```
Local time: Mon 2019-11-18 12:12:50 JST
Universal time: Mon 2019-11-18 03:12:50 UTC
RTC time: Mon 2019-11-18 03:12:50
Time zone: Asia/Tokyo (JST, +0900)
```

Tell me the cause of the warning message and how to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: What is the value of your `TZ` environment variable? Apparently it's not a recognized timezone. Either you've given it an incorrect value, or your computer's timezone database is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

[image: timedatectl e hwclock]

This command, `hwclock --localtime`, returns UTC time listed by `timedatectl`, instead to local.

Answer (score -1):

First run

```
sudo timedatectl
```

if it showed the right timezone then skip ahead to `ls -al /etc/localtime`, otherwise correct it using

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone <your region>/<your location>
```

as an example if you lived in Sweden you would run:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Stockholm
```

then after running this check the output of

```
ls -al /etc/localtime
```

if this points to the wrong timezone then run

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
```

followed by

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/<your region>/<your location> /etc/localtime
```

substituting your region and your location with the same ones used in the last command.

That should fix it, though you might need to `reboot` for the changes to take affect.